# GLua, Function GM:ShouldCollide

Tags: collision-detection, garrys-mod

If the players are on the same team they can collide and if their aren't they cannot.
Players on the same team cannot shoot eachother either because the bullets don't collide with the player if they are on the same team (this is what I want to fix)

```
function GM:ShouldCollide( pl, ply ) -- teams can collide Friendly fire doesn't work bc bullets travel through 
if IsValid(pl) and IsValid(ply) then
    if pl:IsPlayer() and ply:IsPlayer() then
        if pl:Team() == 1 and ply:Team() == 1 then --- guard
            return false
        end
        
        if pl:Team() == 0 and ply:Team() == 0 then
            return false
        end
    end
end

return true
```

end

Answer (score 0):

ply:SetCollisionGroup(COLLISION_GROUP_WEAPON)